# How to implement Firebase Google Analytics in custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, custom-keyboard, firebase-analytics

I want to implement Firebase google analytics in my custom keyboard for button click event.

Anyone please tell me how I can do this in swift.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is normal as using Google Analytics.
Nothing special in keyboard.

Comment: @Zaid Pathan, Normal implementation having big trouble e.g crash [reason: 'Default app has already been configured.']. So that I have asked this question. Could you please help me if you know the solution as I have described my problem in below radugrinico's answer.

Comment: Can you try calling `FIRApp.configure()` twice where ever you're calling?
It may fix the issue. Here is something similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910766/app-crashing-when-using-firebase-auth-reason-default-app-has-already-been-con

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add firebase sdk and GoogleService-Info.plist file to keyboard extension target. Import firebase and configure it. FIRApp.configure() must be called only once per session:

```
import Firebase

class FirebaseConfigurator: NSObject {
static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

static func configure() {
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        FIRApp.configure()
    }
}
```

and

```
FirebaseConfigurator.configure()
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName("button click event", parameters: nil).
```

Comment: I have done the same, but problem is when I switch my custom keyboard to native iOS keyboard and again native to custom then `FIRApp.configure()` method calling again and throwing **error- [reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'] ** and app crash.

Comment: @SunilTarge, you need to make sure that FIRApp.configure() is called only once per session.

Comment: yes I understood but I don't know how to calculate new session of Extension keyboard. because it doesn't have AppDelegate class.

Comment: @SunilTarge, I edited the above code. I moved FIRApp.configure() into a singleton so it will be called only once even if you call FirebaseConfigurator.configure() multiple times.