# Swift 3 Photo Share Extension with Firebase Database Not Working After First Send

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an iOS photo sharing extension in Swift 3 that captures a user-selected photo in the iOS Photos app along with a user-entered caption and stores it in Firebase. The photo is stored in Firebase storage. The caption and the path of the photo in Firebase Storage are stored in Firebase Realtime Database.

The problem I'm encountering is that the share extension stops working after first send. The strange thing is, if I do a similar approach in a regular View Controller in the iOS app, the code works. I noticed two issues with the Share Extension:

Issue #1: The share extension view isn't dismissed completely. In a normal situation, the view would return to a "gallery" mode of Photos. However, the share extension view is going away but the share menu with the complete list of apps that you can use to share is not dismissing.

[Screenshot of what the Photos view looks like after the second send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msNYS.jpg)

Issue #2: the data isn't being sent up to Firebase storage or Firebase database.

Below please find my ShareViewController code:

```swift
import UIKit
import Social
import Firebase
import MobileCoreServices

class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var storageRef: StorageReference!

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return true
    }

    override func didSelectPost() {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        ref = Database.database().reference()
        storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.

        if let item = self.extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem {
            for ele in item.attachments!{
                let itemProvider = ele as! NSItemProvider

                if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.jpeg"){
                    itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.jpeg", options: nil, completionHandler: { (item, error) in

                        do {
                            var imgData: Data!
                            if let url = item as? URL{
                                imgData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                            }

                            if let img = item as? UIImage{
                                imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
                            }

                            var updateRef = self.ref.child("demo_group").child("demo_patient").child("demo_updates").childByAutoId()
                            var updateStorageRef = self.storageRef.child("demo_photos" + "/\(Double(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000)).jpg")

                            updateRef.child("event_name").setValue(self.contentText)
                            updateRef.child("sender").setValue("demo_ff")

                            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                            metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

                            updateStorageRef.putData(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("Error uploading: \(error)")
                                    return
                                }
                                // use sendMessage to add imageURL to database
                                updateRef.child("photos").childByAutoId().setValue(metadata?.path)
                            }

                        } catch let err{
                            print(err)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
        return []
    }

}
```

Please let me know if there's anything I can do to fix this! I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by stubbing/removing all the firebase stuff. It's probably not the problem, but it muddy the waters at the moment

Comment: Are you sure the share extension is authenticated with Firebase? As far as I can tell, the FirebaseApp.configure() does not guarantee that your share extension is authenticated as the same user as your app.

Comment: The first share is authenticating as expected, so I'm guessing it's not an authentication issue. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App crashing when using Firebase Auth, reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910766/app-crashing-when-using-firebase-auth-reason-default-app-has-already-been-con)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FirebaseApp.configure() will crash your extension if call multiple times in a row because the system does not fully deallocate the firebase app instance created for the extension.

My solution was to do:

```
if let _ = FirebaseApp.app() {...} else {
     FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

This should fix your problem.

Edit: Also note that you should call extensionContext.complete after your storage & database updates have completed... Not before

So, you will need to use the methods for setValue that take a completion block. 
1- Upload to storage, when the task completes 
2- Update the database reference,
3- When that completion block is called... Then you call extensionContext.completeWith() or .cancel()