# Unable to run flutter app on IOS - Default app has been already configured

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I had just setup firebase in my app and tried to run it on my iOS device through Xcode, after a long wait the app got installed on my phone but wouldn't launch, the error shown was as follows -

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'**

This is my AppDelegate.swift file -:

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Please help me solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910766/app-crashing-when-using-firebase-auth-reason-default-app-has-already-been-con

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: // Configure Firebase
    // ------------------
    if FIRApp.defaultApp() == nil {
        FIRApp.configure()            
    }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding this line of code -

```
// Configure Firebase // ------------------ if FIRApp.defaultApp() == nil { FIRApp.configure() }
```

You can also check a similar issue for a detailed answer -

[App crashing when using Firebase Auth, reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910766/app-crashing-when-using-firebase-auth-reason-default-app-has-already-been-con)